# Nsarray inside an Nsdictionary shows wrong values In swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Below Code

```
let emailArray : [String?] = [email]


        let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "subject": "subject" as AnyObject,
            "emails" :emailArray as AnyObject ,
            "message" : comment as AnyObject

        ]
        print(dictionary)
```

While printing i am getting dictionary as

```
["emails": <Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x608000628320>(
sasa@pylit.in
)
, "message": EWQF , "inclideReview": 0, "subject": subject]
```

How can i remove `<Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x608000628320>`from this? I tried a lot but no luck !

Answer (score 1):

Change your dictionary to `[String: Any]` and remove the `as AnyObject` from each line

Comment: Yes. your output could be **["emails": [Optional("balaji@fmail.com"), Optional("balaji@fmail.com")], "subject": "subject"]**

Comment: Ty hamish, my mistake +1